# Node.js javascript-barcode-reader gives null on scanning image

Tags: javascript, node.js, barcode, barcode-scanner, node-canvas

I am working on reading multiple barcodes, from uploaded images in node.js. For that I am using [javascript-barcode-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-barcode-reader), which needs **ImageData** as input. to get **ImageData** of an image, I had to make use of [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) (*as I have to do it all in Nodejs, not front-end*).

bellow code executes without any warning/error. Currently, I am only using a single barcode image, but I am getting `code` as null.

what is going wrong here, why I am getting *null* value.

```
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const javascriptBarcodeReader = require('javascript-barcode-reader');

var filepath = './images/Code-2of5.jpg';
var buf = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
var canvas = new Canvas(640, 480);
var Image = Canvas.Image;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

fs.readFileSync(filepath, function (err, squid) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let img = new Image;
    img.src = squid;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    }
});

let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
const code = javascriptBarcodeReader(imgData /* ImageData */ , { 
    barcode: 'code-2of5', // 'code-128'
    type: 'interleaved', //standard/interleaved optional type
});

console.log(code); // output as null
```

Initially, I am trying out for only single barcode image.

[image]

Comment: can you share your image also?

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 gotchas here:

1. invalid usage [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) with callback.
2. assigning `img.src` before register `img.onload` handler.

check this working example both sync and promisified version

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const Canvas = require('canvas');
    const javascriptBarcodeReader = require('javascript-barcode-reader');

    function readBarCodeSync(imagePath) {
      const canvas = new Canvas(640, 480);
      const Image = Canvas.Image;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      const img = new Image;
      img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      }
      img.src = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);

      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
      const code = javascriptBarcodeReader(imgData /* ImageData */ , {
        barcode: 'code-2of5', // 'code-128'
        type: 'interleaved', //standard/interleaved optional type
      });

      return code;
    }

    function readBarCode (imagePath) {
      const canvas = new Canvas(640, 480);
      const Image = Canvas.Image;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      const img = new Image;
      img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      }
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(imagePath,(err,buf)=>{
          if(err) return reject(err);
          img.src = buf;
          const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
          const code = javascriptBarcodeReader(imgData /* ImageData */ , {
            barcode: 'code-2of5', // 'code-128'
            type: 'interleaved', //standard/interleaved optional type
          });
          resolve(code);
        });
      });
    }

    var imagePath = './images/Code-2of5.jpg';

    console.log('sync version', readBarCodeSync(imagePath))
    readBarCode(imagePath)
    .then(barCode=>{
      console.log('async version', barCode);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.error(err);
    })
```

Comment: I am still getting *null*, printed value of 
`buf` <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0a 0c 14 0d 0c 0b 0b 0c 19 12 13 0f ... >

but `imgData` gives all 0.

Comment: the above example gives
`
sync version 1520152015201520
async version 1520152015201520
`
are you sure you applied the same logic?

Comment: what version of javascript-barcode-reader did you tried on, there is version updated on the same day, I asked question and you answered. I was using (V0.3.1).